# Turn a JSON array of arrays into <ul> and <li> elements

Tags: jquery, json, typescript, d3.js, powerbi

I'm creating a custom visual in Microsoft Power BI. The creation api uses typescript and the d3 library. I'm also using jquery

I'm trying to create a hierarchical tree that represents the fields that are dragged into the visual. So the depth of the tree is decided during run-time so It doesn't know how many layers it will have.

I've managed to arrange my dummy data into a nested JSON array.

This is a screenshot from the console when I do console.log(finalViewModel)

[image: screenshot]

```
[{ "text": "France","id": 591, "parent": 0, "identity": {long text},
   "nodes"
        [{"text": "Bread", "id", 478, "parent": 591, "identity: {long text}, 
        "nodes" []}, 
        {"text": "Nocco", "id", 498, "parent": 591, "identity: {long text}, 
        "nodes" []}, 
        {"text": "Red Wine", "id", 718, "parent": 591, "identity: {long 
        text}, 
        "nodes" []}]},
   {"text: "Germany", "id" .....so on and so forth
```

This is how my data looks when I JSON.stringify it in the console, also I used only 2 fields so It wouldn't be too cluttered.

**"identity": {long text}**, does not display like that. The identity field is for the Power BI selection manager so when something from the tree is clicked it will render into other visuals. **long text** Is a replacement for a very long array that holds the information for that certain item identity.

**Now to the problem, I want to convert my JSON data into ul and li elements**. Like this:

```
 <ul>
    <li>France</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Baguette</li>
        <li>Nocco</li>
        <li>Red Wine</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Germany</li>
</ul>
```

I've found many solutions to this kind of problem on the web but nothing seems to fit my needs.

Can anyone help me with a working code snippet?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a demo how it could be achieved with the pure javascript.

```js
var createSublist = function(container, args) {
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  
  for(var j = 0; j < args.length; j++) {
    var row = args[j];
    
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = row.text;
    
    var nodes = row.nodes;
    if(nodes && nodes.length) {
      createSublist(li, nodes);
    }
    
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
  
  container.appendChild(ul);
};

var data =[  
   {  
      "text":"France",
      "nodes":[  
         {  
            "text":"Bread"
         },
         {  
            "text":"Nocco"     
         }
      ],

   },
   {  
      "text":"Italy",
      "nodes":[  
         {  
            "text":"Pizza"
         },
         {  
            "text":"Wine",
            "nodes": [
              { 
               "text": "Red"
              },
              { 
               "text":"White"
              }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
];

var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];  
if(container) 
{ 
  createSublist(container, data);
} 
else 
{
  console.log('Container has not been found'); 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript **ES6** and a small **recursive function**

```js
/**
 * Convert Tree structure to UL>LI and append to Element
 * @syntax getTree(treeArray [, TargetElement [, onLICreatedCallback ]])
 *
 * @param {Array} tree Tree array of nodes
 * @param {Element} el HTMLElement to insert into
 * @param {function} cb Callback function called on every LI creation
 */

const treeToHTML = (tree, el, cb) => el.append(
  tree.reduce((ul, n) => {
    const li = document.createElement("li");

    if (cb) cb.call(li, n);
    if (n.nodes?.length) treeToHTML(n.nodes, li, cb);

    ul.append(li);
    return ul;
  }, document.createElement("ul"))
);





// DEMO TIME:

const myTree = [{
  "id": 1,
  "parent_id": 0,
  "name": "Item1",
  "nodes": [{
    "id": 2,
    "parent_id": 1,
    "name": "Item2"
  }]
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "parent_id": 0,
  "name": "Item4",
  "nodes": [{
      "id": 9,
      "parent_id": 4,
      "name": "Item9"
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "parent_id": 4,
      "name": "Item5",
      "nodes": [{
        "id": 3,
        "parent_id": 5,
        "name": "Item3"
      }]
    }
  ]
}];

treeToHTML(myTree, document.querySelector("#demo"), function(node) {
  this.textContent = `${node.parent_id} ${node.id} ${node.name}`
});
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```