# How to foreach JSON to HTML ul li

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON like below

```
{
    "gists": [
        {
            "name": "Get the title",
            "id": "beaf8a106e76f4bb82a85ca3a7707a78",
            "category": "Function"
        },
        {
            "name": "Get the content",
            "id": "c6ae7c55aa27f8b6dbeb15f5d72762ec",
            "category": "Uncategorized"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to foreach & get as HTML via JavaScript. Like below:

```
<ul>
    <li>Name: Get The title, ID: beaf8a106e76f4bb82a85ca3a7707a78, Function: Function</li>
    <li>Name: Get The content, ID: c6ae7c55aa27f8b6dbeb15f5d72762ec, Function: Uncategorized</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried this way: http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/SLHTA/10/

But, I am not sure how to get values in one line & I want to do it using plain JS. Also my JSON will be form external link. http://rasel.tech/gist.json

This might be a very dumb question. I am sorry :(

Comment: can you post here what you tried  ?

Comment: Are you using any libraries, such as jQuery, or just plain vanilla javascript?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/SLHTA/10/ I tried this way. But I am not sure how to get items in one line. 

@RayChan I want to use plain JS.

Comment: Put what you've tried **in** the quesiton, not just linked. Links can rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. You can use Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). [Here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn a JSON array of arrays into <ul> and <li> elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50966117) and [Use JQuery to convert JSON array to HTML bulleted list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189365/use-jquery-to-convert-json-array-to-html-bulleted-list)

Comment: "Dumb" questions are fine, incomplete or duplicate ones are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With vanilla JS, you can loop through the array with the forEach method and construct the li elements accordingly.

```js
var data = {
    "gists": [
        {
            "name": "Get the title",
            "id": "beaf8a106e76f4bb82a85ca3a7707a78",
            "category": "Function"
        },
        {
            "name": "Get the content",
            "id": "c6ae7c55aa27f8b6dbeb15f5d72762ec",
            "category": "Uncategorized"
        }
    ]
};

var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var ul = document.createElement('ul');

data.gists.forEach(function (item) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');

  li.textContent = 'Name: ' + item.name + ', ID: ' + item.id + ', Function: ' + item.category;
  ul.appendChild(li);
});

container.appendChild(ul);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to stringify object and i used regex to remove `{}` from string.

```js
let obj = {"gists": [{"name": "Get the title","id": "beaf8a106e76f4bb82a85ca3a7707a78","category": "Function"},{ "name": "Get the content","id": "c6ae7c55aa27f8b6dbeb15f5d72762ec","category": "Uncategorized"}]}

let li = document.getElementById('list');
obj.gists.forEach( e => {
  let ele = document.createElement('li')
  ele.innerHTML = `${JSON.stringify(e).replace(/[{}]/g,'')}`
  li.appendChild(ele);
})
```

```html
<ul id='list'>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the items in one line you can do it with css.

You can add `white-space:nowrap;` in your `ul` and `display: inline` in `li`. I am just editing your added fiddle.

```js
var data = {
    "qA": [{
        "question": "How deep is the ocean",
            "answer": [
            "quite deep",
            "very deep",
            "no deep at all"]
    }, {
        "question": "How high is the sky",
            "answer": [
            "real high",
            "high enough",
            "not that high"]
    }]
};

var html = "";
$.each(data.qA, function (index, item) {
    //console.log(item);
    html += "<ul>" + item.question;

    $.each(item.answer, function (index1, item1) {
        html += " <li> ("+index1+ ") " + item1 + "</li>";

    });
    html += "</ul>";
});
$("#container").append(html);
```

```css
ul{
  white-space:nowrap;
}
ul li{
  display: inline
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```